# i have issue in micro integrator

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-micro-gateway

iam trying to running micro integrator standalone in cmd

this issue is appear

Unable to get Charset 'cp65001' for property 'sun.stdout.encoding', using default UTF-8 and continuing.
Unable to get Charset 'cp65001' for property 'sun.stdout.encoding', using default UTF-8 and continuing.
Unable to get Charset 'cp65001' for property 'sun.stdout.encoding', using default UTF-8 and continuing.
[2023-09-28 18:32:02,273]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8290
[2023-09-28 18:32:02,279]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8253
[2023-09-28 18:32:02,281]  INFO {StartupFinalizer} - WSO2 Micro Integrator started in 12.95 seconds
[2023-09-28 18:32:02,478]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through EI_INTERNAL_HTTP_INBOUND_ENDPOINT Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9201
[2023-09-28 18:32:02,497]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through EI_INTERNAL_HTTPS_INBOUND_ENDPOINT Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9164
[2023-09-28 18:37:31,088]  INFO {CoreServerInitializer} - Gracefully shutting down WSO2 Micro Integrator...
[2023-09-28 18:37:31,091]  INFO {ServerManagement} - Starting to switch to maintenance mode...

iam trying to run micro integrator

Comment: what's your micro integrator version,your java version and the Operating System you are using ?